# Tcolorbox: Background color of subtitle

Tags: tcolorbox

How can I correct the transition between the background-colors? The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=bicolor,title=Main Title,
    colframe=red!75!black,colback=blue!10!white,colbacklower=green!10,width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth]
    The upper part. \par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~
\tcblower
\tcbsubtitle[before skip=\baselineskip]%
      {My subtitle}
    The lower part.
  \end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Thanks a lot; Harald

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really wierd and is probably a bug. The hack in the code below fixes the problem to produce:

[image]

but I don't understand what is happening. The `before skip=...` is supposed to take care of this but adjusting the skip amount alone does not fix the problem. Similarly, it should be possible to do this using only a `\vskip` command but I could not get this to work either. I was only able to fix the problem by having both a `\vskip` and  a `before skip`. Here's the hack:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=bicolor,title=Main Title,
    colframe=red!75!black,colback=blue!10!white,colbacklower=green!10,
    width=0.5\linewidth,
    height=0.5\linewidth]
    The upper part. \par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par 
    ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~
\tcblower\vskip-\baselineskip
\tcbsubtitle[before skip=-\baselineskip]{My subtitle}
    The lower part.
  \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

You may need to adjust the `\vskip` amount as I think that `-\baselineskip` puts the subtitle a fraction too high, but using this was more asthetically pleasing than choosing a random distance.

Comment: interesting ... your solution also work with `\tcblower\vskip0pt` :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, I'd hadn't noticed this. There must be funny skips in the tcolorbox code, but I haven't looked.

Comment: @Andrew, it seems that this skip somehow anchor `\tcblower`. why, i don't know either. in come cases i observe that it behavior as `strut`, but i'm not programmer (and may be wrong) ...

Comment: I've reported this as an issue with `tcolorbox` at https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/36

Answer (score 5):

Deliberately, there is some distance between the separation line and the content of the lower box part. Adding the `draft` options helps to understand what happens:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=bicolor,draft,title=Main Title,
    colframe=red!75!black,colback=blue!10!white,colbacklower=green!10,width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth]
    The upper part. \par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~
\tcblower
\tcbsubtitle[]%
      {My subtitle}
    The lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The distance between the `bicolor` separation line and the content of the lower part is `middle` (default: 2mm) plus `boxsep` (default: 1mm). You see these distances in white and pink color.

The subtitle starts exactly at the begin of the lower part (you may spot the dashed line at the top of the subtitle).

To move the subtitle upwards to the separation line, one could use `enlarge top initially by` to change the bounding box of the subtitle. This works as long as the height of the subtitle is larger than the corrected distance. Actually, I would add a small additional distance to avoid optical glitches when two lines are matched, e.g. use `3.1mm` for the default values:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=bicolor,title=Main Title,
    colframe=red!75!black,colback=blue!10!white,colbacklower=green!10,width=0.5\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth]
    The upper part. \par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~\par ~~~
\tcblower
\tcbsubtitle[enlarge top initially by=-3.1mm]% -(middle+boxsep+tinydelta)
      {My subtitle}
    The lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint and for the "background" information